# Compiler error - not seeing PCL *.h files (using Makefile)

Tags: makefile, path, pcl

Anyone using the Point Cloud Library (PCL) with a Makefile (not CMake) who can help me resolve an error please.

I get a compile error which indicates that the compiler is not seeing the PCL path.

In my main.cpp file I include several PCL *.h files  e.g. #include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h> However I get this error when compiling: **src/main.cpp:35:10: fatal error: pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h: No such file or directory**

In my Makefile (see below) I include the path to PCL with "**INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/pcl-1.13**"
and **$(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@**

**I don't understand why the compiler is not seeing the PCL *.h files. Is my Makefile not including the PCL path correctly?**

I have double checked that the path to PCL is correct and it is. See screenshot:

> [image]

This is my Makefile:
(note: I'm new to Makefiles)

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c++17 
INCLUDES = -Iinclude -I/usr/include/glm -I/usr/local/include/GLFW **-I/usr/include/pcl-1.13**
LFLAGS = -lGLEW -lGL -lGLU -lglfw -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldl -lm -lXinerama -lXcursor -lrt -lX11 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
-llibpcl_apps -llibpcl_outofcore -llibpcl_people -lOpenNI -llibusb-1.0 -lOpenNI2 -llibpcl_surface -llibpcl_keypoints \
-llibpcl_tracking -llibpcl_recognition -llibpcl_registration -llibpcl_stereo -llibpcl_segmentation -llibpcl_features -llibpcl_filters \
-llibpcl_sample_consensus -llibpcl_ml -llibpcl_visualization -llibpcl_search -llibpcl_kdtree -llibpcl_io -llibpcl_octree -lpng -lz -lOpenNI \
-llibusb-1.0 -lOpenNI2

SRC = $(wildcard src/*.cpp) 
CFILES = $(wildcard src/*.c) 
SRCDIR = src
BUILDDIR = build
_OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o) $(CFILES:.c=.o)
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
TARGET = main
TARGETPATH = $(BUILDDIR)/$(TARGET)


$(info OBJ is $(OBJ)) # print the value of the OBJ var to screen
build: $(OBJ) $(TARGET)

run:
    ./$(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(OBJ) -o $(TARGET) $(LFLAGS)


$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETPATH)
    rm -f $(OBJ)
```

I'm running VS Code as an IDE on Ubuntu 23.10. The PCL version installed is 1.13.0. My code is C++.

In my Makefile I include the path to PCL with "**INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/pcl-1.13**"
and **$(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@**

Here is the compile output from running make:

```
cxa@cxa-H5S2H:~/OpenGL/Zamani - OpenGL PCL$ make -B
OBJ is src/main.o src/PlyLoader.o src/glad.o
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++17    -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp:35:10: fatal error: pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h: No such file or directory
   35 | #include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h> //for fromPCLPointCloud2()
  |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: src/main.o] Error 1
cxa@cxa-H5S2H:~/OpenGL/Zamani - OpenGL PCL$
```

I expect that this is sufficient for the compiler to find the *.h PCL files which I include in my main.cpp file e.g. #include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h>

**Improved Makefile:**

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c++17 
CFLAGS = -Iinclude
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/pcl-1.13 -Iinclude -I/usr/include/glm -I/usr/local/include/GLFW
LFLAGS = -lGLEW -lGL -lGLU -lglfw -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldl -lm -lXinerama -lXcursor -lrt -lX11 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
-llibpcl_apps -llibpcl_outofcore -llibpcl_people -lOpenNI -llibusb-1.0 -lOpenNI2 -llibpcl_surface -llibpcl_keypoints
#note: have deleted further (long list of) linked libraries to improve readability

#LDFLAGS = -lGLEW -lGL -lGLU -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldl -lm -lXinerama -lXcursor -lrt

SRC = $(wildcard src/*.cpp) 
#SRC += $(wildcard common/*.cpp)
CFILES = $(wildcard src/*.c) 
#$(info SRC is $(SRC)) # print the value of the SRC var to screen
SRCDIR = src
BUILDDIR = build
_OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o) $(CFILES:.c=.o)
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
TARGET = main
TARGETPATH = $(BUILDDIR)/$(TARGET)
#$(info TARGETPATH is $(TARGETPATH))


$(info OBJ is $(OBJ)) # print the value of the OBJ var to screen
build: $(OBJ) $(TARGET)

run:
    ./$(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(OBJ) -o $(TARGET) $(LFLAGS)


$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETPATH)
    rm -f $(OBJ)
```

Makefile compile output for improved Makefile:

```
cxa@cxa-H5S2H:~/OpenGL/Zamani - OpenGL PCL$ make -B
OBJ is src/main.o src/PlyLoader.o src/glad.o
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++17  -I/usr/include/pcl-1.13 -Iinclude -I/usr/include/glm -I/usr/local/include/GLFW  -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/pcl-1.13/pcl/PCLHeader.h:3,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.13/pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h:9,
                 from src/main.cpp:35:
/usr/include/pcl-1.13/pcl/memory.h:48:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
   48 | #include <Eigen/Core>  // for EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: src/main.o] Error 1
cxa@cxa-H5S2H:~/OpenGL/Zamani - OpenGL PCL$
```

Answer (score 1):

When asking questions please show the command that you typed, the compile command make generated, and the errors you got, cut and pasted and formatted as a code block.

Make will print out the commands it invokes.  Look at the compile line make prints.  Do you see the `-I/usr/....` option there?  If not, that's your problem.

This is pretty much definitely wrong:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(SRCDIR)/%.c
       $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This rule tells make that it can build a `.o` file but *only* if it finds **both** a corresponding `.cpp` *and* `.c` file.  So it would only use this rule to build `obj/foo.o` if it could find both `src/foo.cpp` and `src/foo.c`, which is almost certainly not the case, and so this rule is not used.

You have to write two different rules, if you have two different source files:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
       $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
       $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: By splitting out the rules for building the *.c and *.cpp files, as you advise, I now include the paths relevant only to building either the *.c or the *.cpp files.

My initial makefile did not show the "-I/usr/...." in the compile output.

With the changes (added to the OP) I see the "-I/usr/...." in the makefile compile output and I don't get the initial errors shared in the OP.

Getting other errors but am on the right track. Just need to add further paths to CPPFLAGS.

Another important change was also changing "$(INCLUDES) to "$(CPPFLAGS)" and "$(CFLAGS)"

Thanks again.